# jquery - dynamically created form only passing some of the input post data on form submit (form closed prematurely)

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, post

I have an entire form which is created dynamically via jQuery. It submits fine with an `onclick` event from a `<input type="button">` at the end of the form (**side note: the form *does not* submit with an `<input type="submit">`. I don't know why but it could be relevant.**). My problem is that for some reason, when I `print_r($_POST);` after submission, only two pieces of `$_POST` data end up passed, **namely name=selectedID and name=CustomID**. The rest of the `<input>`s don't pass their data.

Here is how the form gets created:

```
var sid = servHTMLid.replace("serviceSel", "");

var cidText = $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(2)").html();
$("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(2)").html("<form name='serviceForm' id='serviceForm' method='POST' action='services.php?save'><input type='hidden' name='selectedID' id='selectedID' value='" + sid + "' /><input type='text' name='CustomID' id='CustomID' value='" + cidText + "' />");

// seems like from here out, these inputs don't POST
var catText = $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(3)").html();
$("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(3)").html("<input type='text' name='Category' id='Category' value='" + catText + "' />");

var nameText = $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(4)").html();
$("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(4)").html("<input type='text' name='Name' id='Name' value='" + nameText + "' />");

var durationText = $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(5)").html();
$("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(5)").html("<input type='text' name='Duration' id='Duration' value='" + durationText + "' />");

var priceText = parseFloat($("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(6)").html()).toFixed(2);
$("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(6)").html("<input type='text' name='Price' id='Price' value='" + priceText + "' />");

var taxText = $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(7)").html();
if (taxText == "yes") {
  $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(7)").html("<input type='checkbox' name='Tax' id='Tax' checked />");
} else {
  $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(7)").html("<input type='checkbox' name='Tax' id='Tax' />");
}

var InactiveText = $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(8)").html();
if (InactiveText == "yes") {
  $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(8)").html("<input type='checkbox' name='Inactive' id='Inactive' checked />");
} else {
  $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(8)").html("<input type='checkbox' name='Inactive' id='Inactive' />");
}

$("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(9)").html('<input type="button" value="save" name="serviceFormSubmit" id="serviceFormSubmit" onclick="submitForm();" /></form>');
```

Here is a screenshot about to submit the form (with the 'save' button) after it being dynamically created:
[image]

Here is the `print_r($_POST);` output after submitting: 
[image]

Notice there is no $_POST['Category'] or $_POST['Name'] etc.

For good measure, this is the submitting function called by the button's onclick event:

```
function submitForm()
{
 $("#serviceForm").submit();
}
```

**EDIT: Just found out that the generated HTML apparently is closing the form prematurely..??**

```
   <table class="services" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr id="serviceSel6" onclick="openEdits(this.id);">
<td>6</td>
<td>
<form id="serviceForm" action="services.php?save" method="POST" name="serviceForm">
<input id="selectedID" type="hidden" value="6" name="selectedID">
<input id="CustomID" type="text" value="Massage 09" name="CustomID">
</form> // <----- THIS... why?
</td>
<td>
<input id="Category" type="text" value="" name="Category">
</td>
<td>
<input id="Name" type="text" value="Mass Reflexology" name="Name"> // .....etc.
```

Comment: Is there a way to see the **HTML** passed to your browser by your server?

Comment: I'm using Firebug in Firefox. No console errors or anything, and the html is apparently there

Comment: @khaverim : How do you send form data's into `PHP`? Show your html form also..

Comment: @Ranjith the form has `method="post"` and I retrieve the data using PHP's `$_POST` array. There **is no** HTML form. This is how it is created, on the fly, entirely

Comment: What I am saying is, can you post here the generated HTML. You can get that from Firebug.

Comment: @user3558931 i now know that the form was closed off prematurely (see HTML i added). But i have no idea why it would do that or how to prevent it

Comment: That's what I thought. Looking at the generated HTML for correctness and well-formedness saves you a lot of headache. Look through your jquery for generating the form. Debug it carefully.

Comment: See my explanation in the answer below. I hope it make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful about using the jQuery methods creating dynamic html such as `html()`, `append()` and the like.

**Any opening tag without a closing tag is given a corresponding closing tag.** That's why `</form>` appears where you see it.

```
.html("<form name='serviceForm' id='serviceForm' method='POST' action='services.php?save'><input type='hidden' name='selectedID' id='selectedID' value='" + sid + "' /><input type='text' name='CustomID' id='CustomID' value='" + cidText + "' />");
```

`html()` did not see a `</form>` at the end of the string so it added one for you. Usually you would take your time to construct the whole form **string** and then you would invoke the appropriate method:

E.g. `.html( 'Well-formed HTML String' )`

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s3wD7/) <---- Check the console output.

Comment: If this is true.... a pox on `html()`! In my case I need different strings in different places! I'm not putting the whole form all in one element's contents! +1 for this knowledge...assuming it's true, which it sure looks like it.

Comment: You are safer having `<form....` before the table and `</form>` after the table. If the table already exists you could write `$('table').wrap('<form action="..." .../>')` - you don't even need to supply the closing tag, then you can append well-formed HTML into each cell of the table.

Comment: I will forever remember to put `<form>`s outside of `<table>`s. Many thanks. After putting the form opening and closing tags in the initial HTML (not generating them inside the table with jQuery), the POST data went through correctly. +1,000

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to replace the name of the input element with an array

For eg:

```
var catText = $("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(3)").html();
$("#" + servHTMLid + " td:nth-child(3)").html("<input type='text' name='Category[]' id='Category' value='" + catText + "' />");
```

Comment: Using an array instead of the string for a name did not change the result :\

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for the same